# How to add more images on Stores (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop

On Prestashop 1.4 you can add stores on BO "AdminStores", but you only can upload ONE picture, I need to upload more, anybody have some modification for these?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

PrestaShop has a "Spaghetti and meatballs" code architecture. They have (at least they used to have pre 1.4) a very hard coded Admin area mixing PHP-SQL-HTML-inline CSS-inline JavaScript, hrm "the works".

1. You may be able to write a sweet front-end code to associate a Scene to the main home category of that Store you would only need to alter one of the root files.
2. Making a full-working back-end solution without a module implies some serious hacking and non-maintainable code also you can't allow updates.
3. You best bet is finding a module but that needs to implement everything including new DB tables and upload interface etc. and then make sure it associates images to Stores.

When in lack of either, solution no.2 becomes imminently more probable if you have the necessary skills.